# NULL REF error while populating SelectListItem from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have following ViewModel (TripSearchView) which contains IEnumerable(of AffiliateComponentTypeView) property, I have to populate a dropdown list using this collection. I have written an extension class which populates SelectListItem from IEnumerable property.

```
public class TripSearchView
{
    public IEnumerable<AffiliateComponentTypeView> ComponentTypes { get; set; } 
    //More fields...
}
public static class DropDownHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(
                  this IEnumerable<AffiliateComponentTypeView> componentTypes, int selectedId)
    {
        return
            componentTypes.Select(componentType =>
                      new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = componentType.ComponentDesc,
                          Value = componentType.Component_Type
                      });
    }

}
```

This is how I call it in my aspx but I am getting a NULL REFERENCE error for second parameter of Html.DropDownList. I have made sure that `IEnumerable<AffiliateComponentTypeView> ComponentTypes`  is correctly populated with values and the logic to populate the SelectListItem works correctly. Why am I getting a NULL Ref error? What am I missing?

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(Model.TripSearch.ComponentType.ToString(), DropDownHelper.ToSelectListItems(Model.TripSearch.ComponentTypes,0))%>
```

I am populating "ComponentTypes" with collection in my controller action before calling the View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SearchView SearchView = new SearchView();
    TripSearchView TripSearchView = new TripSearchView();
    TripSearchView.ComponentTypes = _referenceDataService.AffiliateComponentTypes(base.GetAffiliateID());
    SearchView.TripSearch = TripSearchView;

    ViewData["ComponentTypesList"] = _referenceDataService.AffiliateComponentTypes(base.GetAffiliateID()).Select(componentType =>
                  new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Text = componentType.ComponentDesc,
                      Value = componentType.Component_Type
                  });

    return View(SearchView);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%: Html.DropDownList(
Model.ComponentType.ToString(), 
Model.TripSearch.ComponentTypes.ToSelectListItems(0))
%>
```

In your DropDownHelper

```
    return componentTypes.Select(
      componentType =>
         new SelectListItem 
            { Text = componentType==null?"empty":ComponentType.ComponentDesc,
              Value = componentType==null?"empty":componentType.Component_Type
            })
```

Are you sure that base.GetAffiliationId is not null? Are you sure the service it self does not throw a null refence exception? Remember that these are IEnumerable so execution might be deffered.

Comment: Rene, I tried your suggestion as well and still getting same error.

Comment: Sorry Rene. You guys were correct, it was my bad. "Model.TripSearch.ComponentType.ToString()" was NULL and I was referancing it for the DropDown name.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of three options:

- `Model.ComponentTypes` is null (you say it's not, but I have to assume that *something* isn't the way you think it is)
- One of the component elements in `Model.ComponentTypes` is null
- One of the component elements has a null `ComponentDesc` or `Component_Type`

I note that you're not using the `selectedId` parameter in the method, by the way... did you mean to? (You're also not using the fact that you've got an extension method, for some reason...)

Comment: Jon, I have edited my post by adding my controller action and you can see that "ComponentTypes" is being populated with values and I have made sure while debugging. Just to make sure, I have also populated ViewData["ComponentTypesList"] with SelectListItem and it does populate however I am getting a Object Ref error in my View. I am not using the selectdId at the moment. I am not sure what you mean by "You're also not using the fact that you've got an extension method, for some reason..."

Comment: Sorry Jon. You guys were correct, it was my bad. "Model.TripSearch.ComponentType.ToString()" was NULL and I was referancing it for the DropDown name.